# JTable not updating after switching between JFrames

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtable

I am switching between 2 `JFrame` windows, but when I switch I am trying to update a `JTable` when you switch because one frame is to add an employee and the other is to display a table of the employees. And so after you add the employee and go back to the original frame it should update the table. The problem is that the method to update the table doesn't run.

Here is the code for the frame containing the table:

```
public class employeeUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

ArrayList<employeeClass> employeeList = new ArrayList<employeeClass>();

/**
 * Creates new form employeeUI
 */
public employeeUI() {
    initComponents();
    readfromFile();
    populateTable();
    getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(23, 76, 79));
}

public void populateTable() {
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
    Object rowData[] = new Object[7];
    for (int i = 0; i < employeeList.size(); i++) {
        rowData[0] = employeeList.get(i).employeeID;
        rowData[1] = employeeList.get(i).employeeName;
        rowData[2] = employeeList.get(i).employeeEmail;
        rowData[3] = employeeList.get(i).employeeAddress;
        rowData[4] = employeeList.get(i).employeeTitle;
        rowData[5] = "$" + employeeList.get(i).employeeSalary;
        rowData[6] = employeeList.get(i).employeeHire;
        model.addRow(rowData);
    }
}
```

Here's a video demonstrating the problem: https://streamable.com/yscze

Comment: The code you've posted here give us no hint about the cause of your problem. Please create a [mcve] so we can also reproduce your issue and provide a solution.

Comment: `because one jFrame is to add an employee and the other is to display a table of the employees.` - you should only have a single JFrame. The second  window to add employees should be a modal JDialog. One simple solution is to pass the DefaultTableModel to the child dialog. When you enter the Employee information and click on the "Save" button you use the addRow(...) method of the table model to add the new employee information. Note, there is no need for the employeeList ArrayList. The data for the eimployees will be stored in the TableModel. There is no need to have the data in two places.